# Is it possible to create Carrierwave versions after an initial convert has taken place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to convert uploaded files to PNG using

`process convert: 'png'`

This is ok, but I also have several versions of my image, most have to do with resizing. The versions are created from the original image, not from the converted PNG image. I would like the versions to be made from the converted PNG image instead. Is this possible without too much hackery?

Comment: fyi I've opened a Github issue as well https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1130

Answer (score 0):

Not Completely sure on this as I  did it long back but there is method on uploader to  **recreate_versions!**

it goes like [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L214-L228)

Just try on do like this

```
[record].[uploader].recreate_versions!
```

As far I remember it does recreate the versions every time you call it

Comment: Where could I put this so it happens automatically when the model is first saved? Afaik Carrierwave does not have an "after process" hook.